# Trouble installing PySDL2 on Windows. (No module error)

Tags: python, importerror, pysdl2

So I tried to install pySDL2 just now, but I keep getting an error stating:

```
No module named 'sdl2.util'
```

I've followed the directions from the website, so I have no idea why this is not working. And I don't see anyone else asking this.

**1:** *I downloaded: "PySDL2-0.9.2.zip" from BitBucket.*

**2:** *I unzipped the folder and moved the contents out.*

**3:** *I went to my command line, and then navigated to the directory containing the setup.py*

**4:** *I typed (As directed in the [instructions](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html)):* `python setup.py install`

**5:** *The installation seemed to have worked fine, and once the command line was returned to me, I closed it out.*

**6:** *Navigated to the **Examples** folder, and tried to run an example:*

> ImportError: No module named 'sdl2.util'

I then tried importing sdl2, which resulted in the same error. Can anyone tell me why I am getting these errors? Or what I may have done wrong? I don't know what else to provide as information. I really only followed the couple steps provided, and for some reason I can't seem to access SDL2 from python . .

---

**[Update]**

So the sdl2.util error has now been removed. I have installed the required DLL for SDL2 into the Python33's `DLLs` Folder. I then attempted to set the environment variable for the DLL to it's location. (So that I would stop getting error's concerning a missing library, ect). This doesn't actually fix the problem though. The tutorial clearly states that this command should be run from the command line in order to solve my issue:

> set PYSDL2_DLL_PATH=C:\path\to\fancy_project\third_party

I then modified this to point to the location of the DLL file:

> set PYSDL2_DLL_PATH=C:\Python33\Dlls

All good right? Nope. For some reason, this just doesn't work. Every time I want to run an example, I need to continuously set the environment variable as such:

```
os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] = "C:\\Python33\DLLs"
```

If I don't include this, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: could not find any library for SDL2 (PYSDL2_DLL_PATH: unset)
```

It would appear that my environment variable is not set, but why this is the case I don't know. I have tried setting it several times and restarted once. Yet this persists. If anyone can assist it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an Environment Variable for windows with the following parameters:

**Variable Name:** PYSDL2_DLL_PATH

**Variable Value:** PATH_TO_THE_DLL_FILE_LOCATION

Fixed the issue.

Using the Windows `set` command is apparently only temporary.

Answer (score 0):

I first run the command:
**python setup.py build**
then:
**python setup.py install**
And download a dll file named SDL2.dll put it under the folder :**C:\Windows\System32** 
It works for me to run the example code.Hope helps!

Comment: I have followed all these steps. But I still get the same error message.

Comment: Alright, what you actually needed to do concerning the DLL file was place it somewhere and then configure the environment variable to point to it's folder (location). This doesn't actually seem to be working unless manually set in each python file that you intend to use SDL2 with. I've posted in a bit more detail the problem above in my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pip install these requirement as mention in the https://github.com/marcusva/py-sdl2#requirements

```
pip install PySDL2
pip install pysdl2-dll
```