# Unable to Install Pygame_sdl2 on windows 8.1 64 bit OS

Tags: android, python, installation

I have created a pygame application. Now I want to create an APK and for that I need to install pygame_sdl2. However, when I try to install by running python setup.py install I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\pygame_sdl2-master\setup.py", line 36, in <module>
parse_cflags([ "sh", "-c", "sdl2-config --cflags" ])
File "C:\pygame_sdl2-master\setuplib.py", line 93, in parse_cflags
output = subprocess.check_output(command, universal_newlines=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Any help in this context would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the version you need here https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2/downloads
2. Exctract, open the cmd and navigate to the folder.
3. Run python setup.py install

Working for me this way.I downloaded PySDL2-0.9.3.zip file

Comment: I did that and now I am getting Import error 

    ImportError: could not find any library for SDL2 (PYSDL2_DLL_PATH: unset)

<br/>

I am using python 2.7.10 32 bit on a 64 bit windows 8.1 OS

Comment: Generally i think is better to use same bit editions. 64 bit windows, 64 bit python and install 64 bit package for python. For this problem you can check here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441836/trouble-installing-pysdl2-on-windows-no-module-er) for the solution or here http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html